# How to combine ranges in Google Sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have tried to combine columns in a script. Of course I have found multiple answer on this forum. But I didn't find exactly the information I need to be able to complete my code alone.

Here is the actual code that works perfectly but who is very slow:

```
if (hidedatesBAT[i][0] === "date BAT") {

  COPYsheet.getRange(2 + i, 27 , 1, 1).clearContent();
  COPYsheet.getRange(2 + i + 1, 27, 1, 1).clearContent();
  COPYsheet.getRange(2 + i, 28, 1, 1).clearContent();
  COPYsheet.getRange(2 + i + 1, 28, 1, 1).clearContent();

  COPYsheet.getRange(2 + i, 16 , 1, 1).clearContent();
  COPYsheet.getRange(2 + i + 1, 16, 1, 1).clearContent();
  COPYsheet.getRange(2 + i, 17, 1, 1).clearContent();
  COPYsheet.getRange(2 + i + 1, 17, 1, 1).clearContent();

}
```

that I'am trying to replace with:

```
if (hidedatesBAT[i][0] === "date BAT") {
        
  var ranges = COPYsheet.getRangeList(['P2:P' ,'Q2:Q' , 'AA2:AA' , 'AB2:AB']);
  ranges.clearContent();    

}
```

but of course, it delete all the raw on the `var ranges = COPYsheet.getRangeList(['P2:P' ,'Q2:Q' , 'AA2:AA' , 'AB2:AB']);` column, and not only the `i` and `i+1` lines.

Where do I enter those values? And how to write them?

Comment: You're iterating down all the rows in the sheet?

Comment: Can you provide a sample sheet with dummy values so that people in the community will be able to easily replicate your sample?

Comment: Now that I have edit and correct the question, anyway for somebody to delete the -1 evaluation on it, because it still there, and I found it really unfair !

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to make your code more efficient; specifically reducing the number of `clearContent()` commands. You have tried to use `getRangeList` but found that you were not taking the value of `i` into account.

**Comments on the answer/snippet**

- `var rangeArray = []` - a temporary array is created; this is used later in the script
- **The Loop**

  - `for (var i=0;i<xyz.length;i++){`- your script is looping through a range.

    - Your script contains a line like this BUT you didn't include this line in your question.
    - This line is simply an example of the line in your script.

    > **Don't use this line; use the existing line in your script.**
  - `getRange(row, column, numRows, numColumns)` - you are using four `getRange` commands for each set of Columns where one would do.

    - `numRows` = 2
    - `numColumns` = 2
  - `rangeArray.push(...)` - use the temporary array to hold the ranges to be cleared.

    - this line is **within the loop** so it accumulates all the ranges.
- **After the Loop**
- `var rangeList = COPYsheet.getRangeList(rangeArray)`
- `rangeList.clearContent()`

  - Once the loop is complete, you can issue one `clearContent` instruction that will be carried out on every range captured in the loop.
- **About the loop**
  For each value of `i`, you are clearing four cells: two adjacent columns and two rows. This means that if `i` increments by a value of one, then the next value of `i` will clear cells that were cleared by the preceding instruction.

The answer includes a couple of Logger commands. You can un-comment one or both of these to identify the ranges and clarify whether there is any overlap between iterations of the loop.

---

**SNIPPET**

```
  var rangeArray = []
  for (var i=0;i<xyz.length;i++){ // example
    if (hidedatesBAT[i][0] === "date BAT") {
      // Logger.log("DEBUG: The ranges to be cleared are: "+COPYsheet.getRange(2 + i, 27 , 2, 2).getA1Notation()+" and "+COPYsheet.getRange(2 + i, 16 , 2, 2).getA1Notation())
      rangeArray.push(COPYsheet.getRange(2 + i, 27 , 2, 2).getA1Notation(),COPYsheet.getRange(2 + i, 16 , 2, 2).getA1Notation())
    }
  }
  // Logger.log(rangeArray) // DEBUG
  var rangeList = COPYsheet.getRangeList(rangeArray)
  rangeList.clearContent()
```